# How to save ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile object to original file type such as .xls file in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, file-upload

When trying to upload `.xls` file in rails, the `params[:file].tempfile` gives the object of `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile`, is there a way to save it as the original file type in the `Rails.root` path?

In addition, how the ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.path is defined? Is it possible to define the ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.path by myself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`params[:file].path` is where the file saved. To save it in the `Rails.root` path, use:

```
FileUtils.mv(currentPath, newPath)
```